# Is $\infty$ an essential singularity of this function?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have $f(z)=\frac{1}{e^z-1}$. It has poles at each $2nπi$. My guess is that it also has an essential singularity at $\infty$, since the limit at $\infty$ does not exist. For instance if I go along the positive real axis then $f$ goes to $0$. If I go along negative real axis $f$ goes to $-1$.

(I'm asking this because I have a study material saying that each singularity is a pole)

Comment: There will be those who will assume that because introductory text books give the classification of 'removable', 'pole' or 'essential' only for isolated singularities, then they don't want to call that one essential. So be careful if your instructor is one of those. Those people just call it a non-isolated singularity.

Comment: @topeik that must be it

Comment: But it isn't a pole as you have shown. Poles have the distinctive property of the limit being $\infty$. So, they are not really so singular.

Comment: $s=0$ is not an isolated singularity of $f(1/s)$, it is not an essential singularity, ie $f(z)$ doesn't have a Laurent series in $z^{-1}$ valid for $|z|$ large enough (in contrary for $1/f(z)$). The function is meromorphic on the pointed neighborhood and the poles accumulate there.